# Async Triggers in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

I have an update panel, an async trigger and a button outside the update panel. The button is wrapped with the trigger. All this is in one form. I load this form using the .load() method (jQuery). It works fine: I press the tab and the form loads into the other form. Then, when I press the button for the first time it fires the click event, but when I press it again nothing happens. Can you please help? I have tried putting the button in and out of the update panel and it's still not working. Here's my code:

```
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Search" />
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
         <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName = "Click"/>
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
        ...
```

Comment: Something is breaking your viewstate, and fails the second time. If you check up you must have javascript error. Try to remove the UpdatePanel and make the same moves to see if you get any error on the update panel.

Comment: without the trigers its workink good, with them its not

Comment: Something you change that is outside of the update panel, and you break the viewstate

Comment: Did you check the console section of the browser and check if you see any errors in there ??

Comment: Also if that does not not work why don't you try to send an ajax request to the server??

Comment: well i dont know how and thats why i use trigers so i can use the .load() method and load an asp form

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading the form with jquery it may be something where you need to rebind an event, I'm not familiar with the .load method()

I assume this section of code works fine if you pull it off into a test page?

Comment: yes its working fine on its own, but when i set the trigers it doesnt, i get this erorr in the browser console when i press the button for the second time:"70|error|500|The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.|"

Comment: now i have to tell you i havent slept all nait, buti searched for the, solution of the erorr in the console and its work like this: i load an asp for inside an html file not inside another aspx file, and its working, can anyone tell me is this good solution or not i em new in asp, i saw that the prolem wa in the "__VIEWSTATE" variable, thank you in advice.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If you update your question with the source for the whole page we can try to replicate your issue. 


One other thing to think of is, what if you put the button in it's own update panel, and then in the code  behind for it's on_click event call UpdatePanel1.Update()

Thanks,
Andrew